# mkdir: cannot create directory `b': Disk quota exceeded

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive, quota

When i try to create a file or dir on my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
 vserver i get a `mkdir: cannot create directory b: Disk quota exceeded`.
**But:**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      438G  8.4G  406G   3% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
```

- Disc quota is disabled.
- File system is nearly unused.
- The admin says, that the physical HDD is only 25% used.
- `quota -v` returns nothing

How can i create files and folders again?

Comment: What does `quota -v` say?

Comment: Surely you should be getting _the admin_ to fix this ?

Comment: quota -v returns nothing

Comment: @lain well when the admin takes years to fix this i have to try to fix it myself.

Comment: @axaluss: Do you have root privileges on the system ?

Comment: @lain yes i got root privileges on the virtual server. not on the physical machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simfs is a sign of [OpenVZ](http://openvz.org/) in use, it means your VE ([container](http://openvz.org/Container)) is overused its [disk quota](http://openvz.org/Disk_quota).

Answer (score 2):

You may be using the maximum Inodes your partition allows.

So df might show only 3% usage when in fact the inode usage might be 100%.

Try df -hi to verify if the inode usage is too high.

Comment: Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       196K  196K     0  100% /
tmpfs            4.0M     1  4.0M    1% /run/shm
I think thats not the problem

Answer (score 1):

No output from 'quota -v' matches the statement 'quota is not in use'. This may be a sign of some other problem with the filesystem, but the admin would have to do troubleshooting to find out what is wrong.